# Fade effect with .hide() .show() in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found a nice method to split large post, on blogger, into multiple pages here: http://blogtimenow.com/blogging/splitting-long-blog-post-blogger/

I'm trying to add a fade effect when switching pages, but i don't know how to do this, i have no experience when it comes to jquery...

I managed so far to make the page scroll back to the top, and added some animations using time values, but it's not looking quite right.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.page1').click(function(){
jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
jQuery('.content1').show(2000);
jQuery('.content2').hide(1000);
jQuery('.content3').hide(1000);
jQuery('.content4').hide(1000);
jQuery('.content5').hide(1000);
```

So basically what i want is the current "page" to fade out and the next "page" to fade in...

Comment: use jQuery('.class').fadeOut(); / .fadeIn(); / fadeToggle();

Comment: And see http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/ for info

Comment: You can refer doc at http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code**

below javascript will add effect `fadeIn-fadeOut` on page while switching the pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("body").fadeIn(800);
                $("a").not(".no-fade").click(function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    linkLocation = this.href;
                    $("body").fadeOut(400, redirectPage);      
                });
                // Redirects page
                function redirectPage() {
                   window.location = linkLocation;
                }
            });
    </script>
```

- Put above code into `<head>` tag in your `Html` page

Comment: This somehow works, only problems: The fade applies to the whole site, i mean the whole site fades to white when i press the next page button. Basically the result is a white page with nothing on it.

Comment: @Fuzzy1 - you should put this code in your second page also

Comment: Hmm i don't think you understand for what i use this script. Basically i have a big post, and i split it into smaller parts, without making another post.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.page1').click(function(){
jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
jQuery('.content1').fadeIn(2000);
jQuery('.content2').fadeOut(1000);
jQuery('.content3').fadeOut(1000);
jQuery('.content4').fadeOut(1000);
jQuery('.content5').fadeOut(1000);
```

Comment: That worked, thanks... I tried it before and it didn't worked then... strange, maybe i did something wrong,